# Gradle ear plugin generating two application.xml file

Tags: gradle

I have sample project (sample-project) and have a META-INF folder directly under the project and it has three files( application.xml, A.xml and B.xml) when I generate the ear, the build is successful, but the ear META-INF has an additional application.xml file generated by the script.

How can I avoid the additional application.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Put your META-INF files under src/main/resources and modify the build
 ear {
    appDirName 'src/main/resources'

}